# SASS source-mapping disappears after installing an addon ember-paper in ember-cli?

Tags: css, ember.js, sass, material-design, ember-cli

I have installed an addon called ember-paper for material design interactivity.after installing the addon sass source mapping has been disappeared.and it works properly after uninstalling the addon.